# 'Cannot Load This File' Error for gem built in the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to API integration and API calls. For the API I am using, I have to build the gem within the project and require it in the controller I will make API calls in. 
When requiring the gem, despite making several changes between a relative and absolute path, whenever I run the project locally I keep encountering a 'cannot load such file' error. But the path is correct.

I've tried this: 
'../../lib/learning_studio_authentication-0.0.1.gem'

and the full path.

Additionally, my local gems are not showing up when I run 'bundle install' from the command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can post your code snippet of the controller, gemfile, and full backtrace of your error code.

Comment: Hi nayiaw, sorry just saw this response.

My Controller: 
`require 'learning_studio_authentication'
require 'learning_studio_core'`


These gems are not in the project Gemfile but have been successfully installed: 
`learning_studio_authentication 0.0.1 built to pkg/learning_studio_authentication-0.0.1.gem.
learning_studio_authentication (0.0.1) installed.`

Comment: Here is some of the backtrace of error code: 
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in load_dependency'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'

Comment: Sorry, just getting used to the formatting, my comments are unclear.